# How to override Function.length to return the length of an array, in strict mode

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, overriding

I am looking for a way to override the .length property of an Object in JavaScript.

I currently have a wrapper on parent.properties.objects array

(parent is used to for the code to be more readable in context)

This is the basic structure:

(parent variable is defined in namespace and intialized)

```
var parent = function () {
  this.properties = {
    objects: [];
  };
};
```

## wrapper

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  objects = function () {
```

If no argument is passed, assume get

```
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    var _objects = parent.properties.objects;
    return _objects;
```

modify or filter objects

```
    } else if (arguments.length > 0) {
      ...
    }
  };
```

this creates a object.prototype (not [prototype]) variable and adds the method length()

```
  objects.prototype.length = function () {
    var length = parent.properties.objects.length;
    return length;
  }
```

Error

```
  objects.prototype.__proto__.length = function () {    
    var length = parent.properties.objects.length;
    return length;
  }

  parent.objects = objects;
})();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of error you're getting?

Comment: I hacked it with objects.Length() (JavaScript being case sensitive).
I'm doing this as to write a comfortable API, and not to have a function for every property get/set operation. but a single function for every property. It would've been nice to call objects.length(), but objects.Length() will do, opposed to objects().length() . The error was some kind of __proto__ not found blah blah blah. Will have to wait for ECMA 6.

Comment: What is your last line `parent.object = object;` supposed to do? `parent` is a function, and I don't see a `object` variable declared anywhere

Comment: `parent.properties.objects.length();` - as `objects` is an array, its `length` property is not callable

Comment: Typo for `parent.object = object;`, and I have no excuse for the .length(), thank you @Bergi for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: Please explain what problem you actually face, and what you are intending to do. Your code still makes no sense.

Comment: The goal is a clean API. Overriding `object.length` to call a function would've been prefered. **hack** (!== elegant), `objects.Length = function () { var l = parent.properties.object.length; return l; }`, that is defined in a `extend()` which extends `parent` and executes on initialization, defining a `parent` variable as `this` in anonymous scope `extend(parent.prototype, (function () { var objects=(functions here) ; return {objects: objects} })());`). `parent.objects().length()` did not promote the readability/useabilty of the code in functions that now call `parent.objects.Length()`.

Comment: Your code is pretty confusing.  I think that you are saying that you want getting the property 'length' to call a function rather than just return a property. In ecmascript 5 browsers, this is possible with Object.defineProperty except for one thing - you can't change the length property on arrays or functions.

Comment: I wanted to make a wrapper around an array that executes other functions when data is added or removed. Thank you for the clarification regarding _ECMA5_ properties, I think the time has come to drop _ECMA3_ support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, the following code might help you:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.myActualData = [];
}

Object.defineProperty(MyObject.prototype, 'length', {get: function() {
   return this.myActualData.length;
}});
```

And here's an example of it in use:

```
var x = new MyObject();
x.myActualData.push("Hello");
x.myActualData.push("World");
x.length; // is 2
```

Note: this will only work on ecmascript 5 and above browsers.

Comment: how can I make it work on an unknown object's name ( MyObject ) , like if the object and its name is being created during page load .. ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but you can do the Object.defineProperty call on any object, not just a prototype.

Comment: Not at all, sorry for bringing back this but undefined.defineProperty will lead to an error. So even in JS everything is an object, the primitive type undefined can't be re-assigned this way.